# Tazz 2e oil leak coming from

Tags: toyota, oil-leak, corolla, tazz

I have a Toyota Tazz 2e engine that has oil leaking what appears to be I thought was the rear main seal, but now notice form the top below intake and above water pipes above bell housing joining the engine. Could it be the rear main throwing oil up or an engine leak? It seems to happen during driving or gear changing and not noticed when idling?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your problem is. Pictures would help.

Comment: Check the breather hole underneath fuel pump. Fuel pump is mounted on cylinder head next to carburetor

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a valve cover gasket that is causing this. That's a relatively small engine and should be easy to diagnose if you remove the upper intake cover or assembly. Use some "Purple Power" or engine degreaser of your choice and wait for it to goto work and observe the engine running. You should be able to see what is leaking at that point. I've heard people say a power washer works, but I'm not partial to that. If you do that, be cautious of electrical and plastic.

if it was your rear main seal, you'd most likely only notice oil on the bottom of the bellhousing and engine. Additionally you could have a leak at your oil sending unit. It's usually located on the side of the cylinder block. They can sometimes leak. They screw in, so when the thread sealant stops working it will leak.

Answer (score 1):

Hi yes it seems like its leaking from ur tapped cover seal cause when u driving ur fan kick in and out as enging gets hot so the oil get blown to the back off the engine now it runs down the back that means it must be leaking some ware on the side or on the back of the tap pad cover cause oil gets thin if its warm. Best glean the engine then let it run hopefully u will find the leak

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood the valve cover gaskets might be leaking, they go bad fro every 120- 170k on most cars, but the main seal(seal btw engine and the tranny) to leak there are 0.01% chances, so I dont think the main seal is leaking.